# SQL group by multiple fields get first occurrence

Tags: sql, group-by

I have this table (sales_lines):

```
id  sale_id  sale_seq_id   other_fields
----------------------------------------
1     1       1
2     1       2
3     2       1 
4     3       1
5     3       2
```

But this table can have a duplicated sale_seq_id (yes, it's an error). Like this:

```
id  sale_id  sale_seq_id   other_fields
----------------------------------------
1     1       1
2     1       2
3     1       2
4     2       1 
5     3       1
6     3       1
7     3       2
```

Lines 3 and 6 are errors, so I should discard them.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the wrong records do

```
delete from sales_lines
where id not in 
(
  select min(id)
  from sales_lines
  group by sale_id, sale_seq_id
)
```

To just delete the correct data do

```
select min(id), sale_id, sale_seq_id
from sales_lines
group by sale_id, sale_seq_id
```

Comment: I shouldn't delete rows from database, but well, this approach can work

Answer (score 0):

I would use correlated sub-query  :

```
select sl.*
from sales_line sl
where sl.id = (select min(sl1.id) 
               from sales_line sl1 
               where sl1.sale_id = sl.sale_id and 
                     sl1.sale_seq_id = sl.sale_seq_id
              );
```

If your DBMS supports window function then you can do :

```
select sl.*
from (select sl.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by sl.sale_id, sl.sale_seq_id order by sl.id) as seq
      from sales_line sl
) sl
where seq = 1;
```

By this way, you will get full row with other fields too.